# Grant SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE to all tables except 1 (or more) in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, security, roles

The user I have should have access to all tables in a database - SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and EXECUTE (ASP code to blame :-P) except for 1 table e.g. `users`.

When granting `db_datareader` and `db_datawriter` this gives them full access to everything and removing the DELETE permission on the `users` table will not work.

There are over 60 tables and was looking for a quicker way than using SSMS to go through every table and do this.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly deny permissions which should take precedence. The syntax is

```
deny delete on dbo.users to username
```

Comment: So I can add db_datareader and db_datawriter and then separately exclude the permission on this specific table, and it should be fine?

Comment: Yes. from MSDN `db_datawriter fixed database role can add, delete, or change data in all user tables.` so if you subtract the permissions on that table you should end up with the set you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hacky cursor and sp_executeSQL (GRANT can't take a variable tablename)

```
declare ctable cursor for 
    select Name from sysobjects where type = 'u'

declare @Name sysname
declare @ExecSQL nvarchar(512)

open ctable
fetch next FROM ctable into @Name

while (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    begin
        if (@Name <> 'MyTableToExclude')
        BEGIN
            SET @ExecSQL = 'grant SELECT on ' + @Name + ' to PUBLIC'
            EXEC sp_executesql @ExecSQL
```

... etc

```
        END
        fetch next FROM ctable into @Name
    end
close ctable
deallocate ctable
```

Minor ... note that you can't grant exec on tables ;)